# Display oembed in repeatable metaboxs using CMB2

Tags: metabox, plugins

I'm using [CMB2](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2) to set up a repeating field of meta boxes but I can't find any documentation on how to get a repeating oEmbed field to display on the front end. With the code below I have the metabox working in the backend:

```
      add_action( 'cmb2_init', 'cmb2_register_repeatable_media_resources_metabox' );

      function cmb2_register_repeatable_media_resources_metabox() {

      $prefix = '_cmb_r_';

        $cmb_group = new_cmb2_box( array(
          'id'            => $prefix . 'resources_media_metabox',
          'title'         => __( 'Media Resources', 'cmb2' ),
          'object_types'  => array( 'resources', ),
        ) );

        // Parent
        $group_field_id = $cmb_group->add_field( array(
          'id'          => $prefix . 'resources_media_group',
          'type'        => 'group',
          'options'     => array(
        'group_title'   => __( 'Entry {#}', 'cmb2' ), 
        'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Entry', 'cmb2' ),
        'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Entry', 'cmb2' ),
        'sortable'      => true, // beta
        ),
          ) );

        // Media Resource Title
        $cmb_group->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
          'name'        => __( 'Media Resource Title', 'cmb2' ),
          'id'          => 'media_resource_title',
          'type'        => 'text',
          ) );

        // Media Resource
        $cmb_group->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
          'name'  => __( 'oEmbed', 'cmb2' ),
          'id'    => $prefix . 'media_embed',
          'type'  => 'oembed',
          ) );

      }
```

I can get the title to show on the front end but not the embedded URL?

```
      <?php $resources_media_group = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_cmb_r_resources_media_group', true ); ?>

        <div>
          <ul>
            <?php foreach ( $resources_media_group as $value ) { ?>
            <li>

              <h3><?php echo $value['media_resource_title'] ?></h3>

              <?php echo $value['media_embed'] ?>

            </li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

So, to answer my own question.

In the functions/backend code I made a mistake with this line:

`'id'    => $prefix . 'media_embed',`

In a repeater field it it doesn't need the prefix and as that is defined in the parent and so it should be:

`'id'    => 'media_embed',`

And for the front end this line:

`<?php $value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'media_embed', true ); echo wp_oembed_get( $value ); ?>`

Was changed to:

`<?php echo wp_oembed_get ($value['media_embed']); ?>`

And that did the trick!